# show/hide fragments and adding it to backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, show-hide, back-stack

I have a menu with 4 menu options... Each of these options shows the corresponding fragment. 
I have 3 functions to add,show and hide a fragment:

```
private void addFragment(Fragment newFragment, String fragmentName) {
    fragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.content_frame, newFragment,
            fragmentName).addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
}
private void hideFragment(Fragment existingFragment) {
    if(existingFragment!=null && existingFragment.isVisible()){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(existingFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }   
}

private void showFragment(Fragment existingFragment) {
    if(existingFragment!=null){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(existingFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

The navitemswitchlogic is as follows:

```
onNavItemSelected(int id) {
      switch (id) {
      case 1: //option 1 - hide rest of the fragments and show Option1Fragment
            hideFragment(option2Fragment);
            hideFragment(option3Fragment);
            hideFragment(option4Fragment);

            if (Option1FragmentDoesnotExist) { //create option1Fragment and add it to FragmentTransaction
                option1Fragment = new option1Fragment();
                addFragment(option1Fragment,"option1Fragment");
            } else
                showFragment(option1Fragment);      
              break;
    case 2:
        //same as option 1
    }
}
```

What I expect to happen:
[image]
Whats happening now:
[image]
I know I am making some mistake adding and retrieving fragments to/from the backstack..But,I am not sure what exactly it is. I tried doing all these as a part of the same transaction as well.. That dint work too.. Also, I dont want to  replace the fragments... Hope I framed my question right.. 
Any help is appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to simplify what your results are and what you expect? It's hard to determine in the paragraph.

Comment: @Codedroid, without copy/pasting from your original question, can you provide an explanation of what you expect to happen?  Then what is happening?  Can you detail what you mean by "MENU", what you mean by "Fragment works"?  If your original explanation was confusing, copying it and pasting it won't likely help explain what you need.

Comment: i actually edited my original question to reflect my comment... I will try editing the actual question again to make it clearer then.. Thanks

Comment: @Prmths.. i added some images to explain the problem.. is it better now? Any idea whats happening? Thanks

Comment: are you removing any view in overridden onDestroyView for your Fragments ?

Comment: @GiGa No Im not... :( If I remove .addToBackStack(null).commit() from the hideFragment() function then the back button works.. But, I get the - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment option2ContentFragment is not currently in the FragmentManager when I try clicking on something(that opens a new activity) on the option1ContentFragment..  Its expected as I dint commit the transaction..

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late to answer this question now, but for those who now come across the similar issue, here is the explanation.

Each back press will reverse a single fragment transaction. So basically what you have in the example above is that you have 2 transactions on navigation click.
1st one is Hiding fragment and second is showing a new one. Once you press back, it will reverse showing new one but nobody will reveal the hidden one and you are left with the Blank/empty screen.
On the next back press you will reverse hide action, so fragment will now appear.

What you need to do is to execute both hiding and showing in a single transaction. In that way, a single back press will know that you want to reverse adding and hiding a fragment below.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(existingFragment).add(newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```